# Graph Algorithm Requested Suggestion

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I need to solve what amounts to a graph problem. I have a set P of particles (designated elements by p(i)) of size n, where each particle is located on a plain and a set X (designated elements by x(j)) of size e with points located on the same plain.

I need to calculate a solution of a list of pairs  (p(i),x(j)) for all n particles, such that the particles will place the most even load possible over time and over exit points when travelling over the plain at a fixed speed s. When a particle reaches the exit point it is removed from the set and the plain.

If the exit points can have a divisor so that higher capacity exit points have more load tolerance, that would be even better.

The exit point load is defined as the rate at which particles arrive at the exit at any point in time (it would obviously vary over time.)

The solution I am seeking doesn't need to be optimal, just "good" in some sense of good that is TBD.

Does anyone have some ideas how to solve a problem like that without doing a numeric simulation? Is it similar to any well known graph problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear.  My first reading of "a solution of a list of pairs (p(i),x(j)) for all n particles" suggested you just want to map each particle to a single x value somehow, but suddenly speed, time and load(?!) enter the picture.

Comment: x(i) is defined as exit point i in the set X. The list indicates which exit point each particle should head for so that the exit point load is minimized. Speed is relevant because it takes a finite amount of time for the particle to reach the exit point, and load is relevant because a close particle places a load on the exit point at an earlier time than a distant particle.

Comment: It's still pretty vague, I have to say.  AFAICT the "rate" at a particular exit that you want to optimise is the number of arrivals per ____ units of time, where ____ is a time quantity you don't specify.  And you don't say how you want to aggregate these measures either over exits *or* over time.  The first step is to choose a single quantity to score a solution, which you can attempt to (exactly or heuristically) minimise/maximise.

Comment: I suggest that instead of minimising arrival rate, you want to *maximise* the time between arrivals at a given exit (this avoids unnecessary assumptions about time windows), and to aggregate across time and across exits you pick the worst (i.e., shortest) interarrival time.  So the objective function to maximise is: the minimum, over all exits i and consecutive ball-arrival events j, j+1 at exit i, of the interarrival time t_{j+1} - t_j.

Comment: If you went with this objective function, then one way to get a good discrete-time solution would be to carve up time into k blocks in total, and stipulate that for any given exit, at most 1 particle can arrive at that exit during any single time block.  Then you can model this as the Assignment Problem (google that), with particles P as one set and the other set consisting of k|X| items, one corresponding to each possible (exit, time block) combination, with a (weighted, if you want) edge between a particle and a (exit, time block) combo whenever that particle could use that combo to exit.

Comment: The above algorithm will guarantee that no *three* balls will go out the same exit in any block of time (no guarantee can be made about two balls: a ball exiting near the end of one time block, and a ball exiting near the beginning of the next time block could be arbitrarily close together in time); you can repeat it, increasing the value of k (or better, binary-searching on this) until it reports that no solution can be found.

Comment: Alternatively, there's an easy greedy solution: order the particles randomly, then repeatedly pick the next particle i, for each exit j calculate the minimum time gap between this particle i and other particle-exit events at already assigned to exit j, and assign particle i to whichever exit gives the best (i.e., largest) gap.  You can repeat this many times and take the best.